# Parallel.ForEach missing/ignoring/jumping over/not adding objects

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

My `_baseBlockContainer.GetBaseBlocks();` returns a `ConcurrentQueue` with `15317` objects. For further processing I want to sort them by `Type`. However, it always "misses" some objects.

It appears that my `Parallel.ForEach` is not thread-safe because the amount of objects within the `ConcurrentQueue` for a `Type` is sometimes less (off by 1 to 250 objects for a `Type`) than when sorted by the synchronous `foreach`; but I do not see where/why.

```cs
var baseBlocks = _baseBlockContainer.GetBaseBlocks();

var baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentQueue<BaseBlock>>();
// results of this always differ
Parallel.ForEach(baseBlocks, bb =>
{
  if (!baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent.ContainsKey(bb.GetType()))
  {
    baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent[bb.GetType()] = new ConcurrentQueue<BaseBlock>();
  }
  baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent[bb.GetType()].Enqueue(bb);
});

var baseBlocksByType = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentQueue<BaseBlock>>();
// results of this are always the same
foreach (var bb in baseBlocks)
{
  if (!baseBlocksByType.ContainsKey(bb.GetType()))
  {
     baseBlocksByType[bb.GetType()] = new ConcurrentQueue<BaseBlock>();
  }
  baseBlocksByType[bb.GetType()].Enqueue(bb);
}
```

Comment: No. When I call `_baseBlockContainer.GetBaseBlocks();` after this method or somewhere else in the class the amount of objects within the Queue didn't change (obviously, since I didn't Dequeue() any anywhere in my code). I see now that my wording was pretty bad. The Parallel.ForEach is just missing / ignoring / not adding some objects to the Dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this:

```cs
if (!baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent.ContainsKey(bb.GetType()))
{
    baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent[bb.GetType()] = new ConcurrentQueue<BaseBlock>();
}
baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent[bb.GetType()].Enqueue(bb);
```

with this:

```cs
baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent.TryAdd(bb.GetType(), new ConcurrentQueue<BaseBlock>());
baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent[bb.GetType()].Enqueue(bb);
```

The problem with your existing code is that if `.ContainsKey` evaluates to `false` in multiple threads at the same time for the same block type, then they will all set the value corresponding to the type to a new queue, erasing any existing queue for that type. That is to say: `ContainsKey` and the indexer are, by themselves, thread safe, but not when used separately in the way you are doing it.

`TryAdd` is thread safe and will only add that key once, rather than rewriting it as assigning to the indexer would.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution did not only fix the problem but also reduces nesting! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is suffering from what is known as [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Using [concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) alone does not prevent race condition to occur. You also have to use them correctly, by utilizing their special atomic APIs. In your case the appropriate API to use is the [`GetOrAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd) method:

> Adds a key/value pair to the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` if the key does not already exist. Returns the new value, or the existing value if the key already exists.

Usage:

```
ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Parallel.ForEach(baseBlocks, options, bb =>
{
    baseBlocksByTypeConcurrent
        .GetOrAdd(bb.GetType(), _ => new ConcurrentQueue<BaseBlock>())
        .Enqueue(bb);
});
```

As a side note, whenever you use the `Parallel.ForEach` method it is advisable¹ to specify explicitly the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism). The default `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is -1, which means unbounded parallelism, which in practice saturates the `ThreadPool`.

¹ <sub>It is advisable by me, not Microsoft. The [general advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism#remarks) offered in the official documentation is that modifying the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` setting is not needed. [Microsoft's argument](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72981#issuecomment-1198200618) is that configuring by default this option to `Environment.ProcessorCount` might result in performance regression, and also that it opens the possibility of deadlock in case one iteration depends on another executing iteration. Apparently Microsoft does not consider the `ThreadPool` saturation to be a serious problem.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your suggestions. One follow-up question: The program will run on a server for a few seconds and should be as fast as possible. Is ThreadPool saturation even a consideration for this task, since no other program will need resources during that time (or in other words I am fine if other stuff runs slower during the processing)

Comment: @MichaelS my opinion is that saturating the `ThreadPool` is wrong in principle. In the case that you describe, the impact of saturating the `ThreadPool` is likely to be non existent, but why do it? It will only serve as a bad habit for the next time that you'll need to use the `Parallel.ForEach`, in which case the impact might be significant.